# Is having a bank account a violation of the mitzvah not to charge interest?

Tags: halacha, money

Since when you have a bank account you are technically loaning money to the bank and charging the bank interest, is this a violation of the negative mitzvah not to charge interest on a loan? Or for a Jewish owned bank only? Or not at all? I can't find an answer by Googling so far I am only seeing other bank related questions. I am talking about just having a normal bank account like a checking and/or savings account like every person has. Thank you!

Comment: Is the person with the bank account lending money or investing in the bank? http://rabbikaganoff.com/tag/jewish-owned-bank/ scroll down to "Corporations"

Answer (score 1):

If the bank is owned by a jew, they are not permitted to pay interest and you are not allowed to take it. See this [source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loans_and_interest_in_Judaism) for the general principle of interest.

That being said, there is a halachiky correct way to pay interest on a loan to a jewish owned bank (or whowever loans the money). And presumably the jewish owned bank could have a similar way worked out to be able to pay the account holder interest according to halacha if they wanted to. See [heter iska](https://www.yeshiva.co/midrash/13712) for more information.

Lastly, once in a while, there is an issue of getting interest on a bank account even if it was setup properly according to halacha. See this [article](https://dinonline.org/2016/11/10/interest-from-bank-account-on-rosh-hashanoh/) when this occurs and how to properly deal with it. The article doesn't explain everything but it gives a source where one can further research the matter.